# How I can kill HttpSession by ID?

Tags: java

I have a very big system and I need to control the sessions. I need that if a user is connected through a session from another pc connects the first section is automatically closed. Now I have the list of all ID along with their users in a list.

Do not know how close the HttpSession.

Comment: There is no uniform way of doing that. It highly depends on the server you used and also your configuration (clustered/non-clustered) etc. You could store the ids in a database with a boolean valid `true`/`false` and create a component that checks if the session is still valid (when accessed) if not invalidate the session. You will also need another component that listens for session invalidations so that they can be removed from the database.

Comment: Have you tried using HttpSession.invalidate()?